# Aluminum Monoacetate Solubility in Aqueous Medium?

Tags: aqueous-solution, water, solubility, boron-family

Does anyone have access to the aqueous solubility value of  [aluminum monoacetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_monoacetate)?

I would expect it to be slightly soluble but I've searched the internet and haven't found any solubility values. : /

---

Comment: I re-edited the link and it seems to work for me. From wikipedia: "Aluminium monoacetate, also known as dibasic aluminium acetate, and formally named dihydroxy aluminium acetate, is a salt of aluminium with acetic acid. It has the formula Al(OH)2(CH3COO)"

Comment: Good. Now the compound is legitimate, after all. Well, I also expect it to be slightly soluble.